# SwiftUI array.isEmpty do not show until received array from Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

Currently have a VStack populating with items from firestore and am trying to display a message if there are no items in the db. It works perfectly but there is a brief second where it shows the "No Items" message before loading the list of items. I understand it simply hasn't gotten the results yet from the db. Is there any way to hold off showing ANYTHING until that call is complete?

```
VStack(alignment: .leading){
if itemList.isEmpty {
    Text(“No items”)
} else {
    ForEach(itemList.indices, id: \.self) { i in
         Text(itemList[I].item)
        }
    }
}
.onAppear() { self.readItems() }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can hold rendering until there is data; that might take way too long. Your code has to always render something, no matter what state the app is in.

But what you can do is set a variable to signal whether data has been loaded, like `isLoaded`, set it initially to `false`, set it to true in the completion handler, and use that to determine what to show. Most commonly, you'll show a single Text view `Loading...` in that case, and then switch over to what you now have once `isLoaded` is true.